# Jenkins: How is Script From Different Repo Being Included?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am trying to debug a shell script that is executed via a Jenkins job.  The first thing the script does is include another script that is in a completely different repo.  My instinct is telling me that the user that Jenkins is executing the script from has access to the directory for the other repo through `$PATH` or some other similar mechanism, but nothing I’m seeing indicates this.

I’ve looked over variables in `http://$host/systemInfo`, tried logging on to the Linux box, switched to various users and searched through command history for each, looked at `$PATH` variable for each, and even tried executing a test shell script with the same include as different users.  Still not seeing anything to indicate how Jenkins is able to include a file from a different repo and have not been able to get the include to work in my test script.

My main questions are:

1. How can I determine what user Jenkins is executing the original shell script as?  I would assume user 'jenkins' but I'm not able to get the include to work in my test script executing as this user.
2. How is Jenkins able to include a script from a different repo?

I'm sure I'm just running into some fundamental Jenkins ignorance on my part but not finding answers.  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer and it seems really obvious now that I see it.  The Jenkins server that the job runs from has a PATH environment variable defined in the server config in the Jenkins interface.  This PATH points to the directory containing the external script.